# Twitter Bootstrap 3 navigation icon doesn't expand in their examples

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to Twitter Bootstrap. When I go to the examples for version 3 in both Firefox and Chrome when I shrink my browser window the navigation collapses to the icon with three horizontal lines. However when I click on that icon I don't get the accordian expanding to see the navigation links.

If I view the examples for v2.3.2 it works just fine.

Is there a work-around at this time for v3 or do people recommend using the older version until this is fixed if this navigation feature is something you really need?

v2.3.2 Example that works
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/starter-template.html

v3.0.0 that doesn't work. 
http://examples.getbootstrap.com/starter-template/index.html

Comment: I don't see it as a problem -- I was around 900px when the navbar was collapsed on 2.3.2, and 768px when the navbar collapsed on 3.0.0 RC1.

Comment: The navbar collapses just fine in 3.0.0 but when you click on the icon it doesn't display the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in example of version 3 doesn't include the `bootstrap.js`

Try: http://plnkr.co/edit/mZOwfoHu0qGh8XfiWFa0?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. I am working on new twitter 3 version but navigation bar is shrinking I needed exactly same like in this example http://examples.getbootstrap.com/justified-nav/index.html

If i use latest bootstrap.css v3 which i download from there site then it is shrinking my navigation bar. Then I saw the bootstrap.css which is used in the above example then I pointed to http://examples.getbootstrap.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css then it worked well. So for a time being I download it and pointing to this new css.

I don't know what the difference is between downloaded and this example version of css..